How to increase comment length?
How to change comment length limit to more than 5000 characters? I want to allow users to post long comments. Thank you.

Do you get an error message? Are your comments exceeding the 64kb MySQL TEXT field max-size?

Yes, when I click submit, it just sends me to white page with error (url is www.example.com/wp-comments-post.php) «Error: Your comment is too long» with «go back» link. I will try to increase MySQL text field max size if possible.

Solved the issue. Thank you @birgire for giving me a hint. First I edited MySQL wp_comments table by changing comment_content rows «Type» from TEXT to MEDIUMTEXT and restarted MySQL. Then created filter in functions.php:
add_filter( 'wp_get_comment_fields_max_lengths', 'my_length' );
function my_length ( $lengths ) {
global $wpdb;

    $lengths = array(
        'comment_author'       => 245,
        'comment_author_email' => 100,
        'comment_author_url'   => 200,
        'comment_content'      => 16777215, //it was 65525
    );
    return $lengths;
}

and it worked :) but let me know if I can make the filter more simpler? without array?! Thank you.

Yes, you can just change that one value in the array passed in. function my_length ( $lengths ) { $lengths[ 'comment_content' ] = 16777215; return $lengths; }

16777215 is a lot though. Do you really need more than 64K? I guess you're posting files, encoded binary data. Are comments really the best way to do that?

Thank you very much. People in Stackoverflow say that according MySQL doc: MEDIUMTEXT | 16,777,215 (224−1) bytes = 16 MiB so I thought I should use max size of MEDIUMTEXT while TEXT |  65,535 (216−1) bytes = 64 KiB.

I'm developing Q&A platform using WP. One of the signed up users asked about WW1 incidents. I decided to give a detailed answer it but it took me 3 days to write it (long text with many images).

Fair enough! That feels to me like it should be a separate blog post (or lesson?) and link to it from the comments, rather than post the whole thing in the comments, especially if it would be interesting to other people too.

People still see it in SERP since its title (the question) is visible in google. There's no difference between blog posts and answers. Google will take the answers as main blog posts.

I meant from a usability perspective, and having reasonable volumes of content on a page, not an SEO perspective.
